# How to recover data from a Huawei P30 Lite with a black screen?

Tags: data-recovery, usb-debugging, huawei

I'd like to recover messages, photos and videos if possible. I know the PIN code to the device and I believe both the fingerprint scanner and face recognition are working just fine.

Device: Huawei P30 Lite (original edition, not the new edition)

USB debugging is not enabled on the device. Although the screen is black, I believe the device is otherwise fully functional.

I've tried:

- HiSuite (failed as required USB debugging)
- `adb devices` via Android Platform Tools (failed as I presume it requires USB debugging)

The device appears like this when connected to my PC via USB:

[image]

Comment: Your main problem is that usually Android phones are not usable before you have logged in the first time after boot. Not sure how Huawai devices handle this, but an Google Android devices after a reboot you have to login using password/pin (no face or fingerprint unlock). If this is also required on your device you could try to connect a simple USB keyboard and type the pin without screen.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Robert . I'll give that a go when I next can.

Comment: HiSuite is backup tool for PC